# Json to PLSQL table -> ORA-00942

Tags: json, function, plsql, datatable

I have a json string parameter. I would like to create a function which gives back a table with the data.

I created a type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE AttachmentResponseType AS OBJECT (
 savePath              VARCHAR (255) ,
 originalFileName      VARCHAR (255) ,
 fileSize              number(20) );
```

I created a list

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE JSON_DOC_JUKEBOX_TBL IS TABLE OF AttachmentResponseType;
```

And a function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION JSONSTRING_TO_JB_TYPE (p_json in varchar2) return JSON_DOC_JUKEBOX_TBL as
resTBL JSON_DOC_JUKEBOX_TBL;
JSON_VAR varchar2(3000);

begin
JSON_VAR := p_json;
with x as (SELECT t.savePath, t.originalFileName, t.fileSize FROM JSON_TABLE(
                JSON_VAR,
                '$' 
                COLUMNS(
                    NESTED '$.AttachmentResponseType[*]'COLUMNS (
                    savePath varchar2(255),
                    originalFileName varchar2(255),
                    fileSize number(20)
                    )
                )
            ) as t) select AttachmentResponseType(x.savePath, x.originalFileName, x.fileSize) bulk collect INTO resTBL from x;
            commit;
    return resTBL;
end;
```

I try to test it, I have a tst table for that with the same columns

```
    declare
    test JSON_DOC_JUKEBOX_TBL;
begin
    test := JSONSTRING_TO_JB_TYPE('{"AttachmentResponseType" : [{
             "savePath" : "dsadsad/dsadas.xaxaxa.pfg",
             "originalFileName" : "xaxaxa.pfg",
             "fileSize" : "12"},
             {
             "savePath" : "dsadsad/1111g",
             "originalFileName" : "1.pfg",
             "fileSize" : "1112"}]}');
             
    INSERT INTO tst
    (savePath, originalFileName, fileSize) values
    (SELECT savePath, originalFileName, fileSize
    FROM test);
    commit;
end;
```

test is highlighted as 'Undefined table'
and when I run, the exception is :ORA-00942

Am I doing something wrong? should I initialise the 'test' table somehow?

Comment: You should remove **values** keyword, and preferably get rid of redundant brackets surrounding the SELECT statement which follows INSERT statement .

Comment: nope, even the pslql developer mark the table reference undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple `TYPE`s, and a `FUNCTION` just to insert the records, why not just use `INSERT INTO...SELECT...`

See example below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tst
(
    savePath            VARCHAR (255),
    originalFileName    VARCHAR (255),
    fileSize            NUMBER (20)
);

INSERT INTO tst (savepath, originalfilename, filesize)
    SELECT savepath, originalfilename, filesize
      FROM JSON_TABLE (
               '{"AttachmentResponseType" : [{
             "savePath" : "dsadsad/dsadas.xaxaxa.pfg",
             "originalFileName" : "xaxaxa.pfg",
             "fileSize" : "12"},
             {
             "savePath" : "dsadsad/1111g",
             "originalFileName" : "1.pfg",
             "fileSize" : "1112"}]}',
               '$'
               COLUMNS (
                   NESTED '$.AttachmentResponseType[*]'
                       COLUMNS (savePath VARCHAR2 (255),
                                originalFileName VARCHAR2 (255),
                                fileSize NUMBER (20))));
```